# How to retrieve the monthly summary for 12 months using laravel query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am making a report whom will display the monthly revenue for each customer from January to December in a single row and I am stuck in writing the correct mysql query.

This is using Laravel query builder which join two tables.

```
$so_h = DB::table('a')
            ->join('b', 'a.book', '=', 'b.book')
            ->select('a.*', 'b.*')
            ->whereMonth('a.doc_date', '=','1')
            ->whereYear('a.doc_date', $current_year)
            ->orderBy('a.book', 'asc')
            ->get();
```

the result should like the following:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Customer</th>
<th> Jan </th>
<th> Feb </th> 
</tr>
<tr>
@foreach($so_h as $key =>$data)
<td>Customer A</td>
<td> 1.1k </td>
<td> 3k </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

till december

Comment: What results do you get from the query?

Comment: groupBy should solve the problem

Comment: there is total column in my table b, when I retrieve the data, I can get the total for January. But I want to get the total for every month in 1 query.

Comment: You need in SQL query like ```SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2019-07-25", "%Y-%m")```, and  group by that field ,